# Can't get value of checked radio with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Here is how I try to get a radio's value on change:

```
var $radios = $('input:radio[name=extract_action]');
$radios.change(function() {
    val = $(':checked', this).val();
    alert(val);
});
```

But alert shows "undefined".
I tried with

```
val = $(':checked', $(this)).val();
```

or even

```
val = $(':checked', $radios).val();
```

But it is the same.

EDIT

Here is HTML markup:

```
<input name="extract_action" checked="checked" type="radio" value="1" /> Ok<br />
<input name="extract_action" type="radio" value="0" /> No
```

Comment: Share your html markup as well.

Comment: `console.log($radios)` and ensure that you are capturing some elements with your selector.

Comment: @crush $radios.change() is binded well

Comment: Why not just `$(this).val()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$(':checked', $radios).val();` is looking for checked children of the elements in `$radios`, rather than filtering the set of radio buttons. Instead, you'll want to use the filter() function:

```
var $radios = $('input:radio[name=extract_action]');
$radios.change(function() {
    val = $radios.filter(':checked').val();
    alert(val);
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7Zgdh/)**

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this

```
$(function(){
  $('input:radio[name="extract_action"]').change(function(){
    alert(this.value);
  });
});
```

> Working [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HFHUW/1/)

Comment: You can use `this.value`, there's no need to create a jquery object out of `this` to obtain its `value`

Answer (score 3):

A more simplified one...

```
 var $radios = $('input:radio[name=extract_action]:checked');
    $radios.change(function() {
        val = $radios.val();
        alert(val);
    });
```